# Aggregate function cannot be used in measure dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

How can I use aggregate function in measure dimension?

I would like to create running total over working days. In these days I have only sales, so I am creating flag:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Days] as (
    COUNT(
        [Measures].[New], EXCLUDEEMPTY
    )
)
```

to indicate it. Now I need to aggregate it, but this code throw me error:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Running] as (
    AGGREGATE(
        NULL:TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].Members).Item(0), 
        [Measures].[Days]
    )
)
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
Mon 1
Tue 2
Wed 3
Thu 4
Fri 5 
Sat 5 <- it could be also 0, NULL, doesn't matter
Sun 5 <- it could be also 0, NULL, doesn't matter
Mon 6
Tue 7
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot use the Aggregate function on calculated measures. I'd use the following MDX:

```
With
Member [Measures].[Days] as
Sum(
    Null:[Date].[Date].CurrentMember,
    IIF(
        [Measures].[New],
        1,
        Null
    )
)
```

Comment: seems like there is an interesting alternative detailed here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/11/17/performance-of-running-sum-calculations-in-sp2.aspx ... I've not tested